# How compile uic with PySide6

Tags: pyside6

I want to compile uic to PySide6 but I don't find how to install pyside6-uic tool. Where can I install pyside6-uic? I downloaded PySide6 but command pyside6-uic doesn't work.

There is a reference here in the title:

https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/tutorials/basictutorial/uifiles.html#using-ui-files-from-designer-or-qtcreator-with-quiloader-and-pyside6-uic

Answer (score 5):

Step 1. If you installed PySide6

```
   a. In a venv then go to your venv's folder.
   b. Globally then go to your python installation folder.
```

Step 2. Go to **Lib** then **site-packages** then **PySide6**.

Step 3. Copy **uic.exe** ( or **uic** if the file extension are hidden) create a folder called **bin** and paste what you've copied inside it.

To compile ui files from:

QtDesigner: From the top menu select Form -> View Python Code... then click on the save icon (floppy disk) from the newly opened window.

Command Prompt: `pyside6-uic.exe mainwindow.ui > ui_mainwindow.py`

PowerShell: `pyside6-uic.exe mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.py`

Answer (score 2):

The `pyside6-uic` tool is supposed to be installed automatically when installing the Python package.

### Check if `uic` is in PATH

When using `loadUiType`, the Qt documentation ([here](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html)) states that :

> The internal process relies on uic being in the PATH. The pyside6-uic
> wrapper uses a shipped uic that is located in the
> site-packages/PySide6/uic, so PATH needs to be updated to use that if
> there is no uic in the system.

But even then, I got the following error :

```
Cannot run 'pyside6-uic':  "execvp: No such file or directory"  -  
Exit status QProcess::NormalExit  ( 255 )
Check if 'pyside6-uic' is in PATH
```

For me, `pyside6-uic` was not located in `site-packages/PySide6/uic`. When reinstalling the module with `pip`, I noticed this message :

```
  WARNING: The scripts pyside6-assistant, pyside6-designer, pyside6-genpyi, 
pyside6-linguist, pyside6-lrelease, pyside6-lupdate, pyside6-rcc and pyside6-uic are 
installed in '/Users/<user>/Library/Python/3.8/bin' which is not on PATH.
  Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, 
use --no-warn-script-location.
```

**So make sure to add the right directory to your `$PATH` variable.**
Once it's done, you will be able to use the `pyside6-uic` command to generate a Python class from a UI file :

```
pyside6-uic mainwindow.ui > ui_mainwindow.py
```

### Loading a .ui from code

You can also load a `.ui` file **from your code** using either:

1. `loadUiType` ([doc page](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/loadUiType.html)) :

> This function generates and loads a .ui file at runtime, and it
> returns a tuple containing the reference to the Python class, and the
> base class.

2. or `QUiLoader` ([doc page](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtUiTools/QUiLoader.html)):

> enables standalone applications to dynamically create user interfaces
> at run-time using the information stored in UI files or specified in
> plugin paths

```
from PySide6.QtUiTools import QUiLoader

ui_file = QFile("mainwindow.ui")
ui_file.open(QFile.ReadOnly)
loader = QUiLoader()
window = loader.load(ui_file)
window.show()
```

Generally speaking, use absolute paths to access your UI files. Relative paths are susceptible to errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you using virtual environment, when you install pyside6 with pip in the virtual environment there is a folder named Scripts there is the pyside6-uic.exe tool.

[image]

if you have install pyside6 globally in your system and you use visual studio code you can use the extension PySide2-vsc then when you installed you can go to preferences > settings and search the PySide2-vsc extension settings then look for the "Command to compile a .ui file into python". Then you can use that feature with right-click on .ui files.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this issue to add this Path to my %PATH% Variable on windows.

```
C:\Users\<YOUR_USER_PATH_NAME>\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\Scripts
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in the following way.

If pyside6 is installed globally

```
uic -g python form.ui > ui_form.py
```

You can find more information on:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-using-a-ui-file-python.html

Comment: I can't testify on Linux/Win OSs, but for MacOS PySide6 provides uic under the Qt Designer folder and not under Scripts. And in any case, The same code can be retrieved from the Qt Designer menu "Form -> View Python Code..."