# pyside6-uic : The term 'pyside6-uic' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet(Using Windows 11 and Pycharm)

Tags: python, pyside6

I was learning how to use PySide6 and Qt Designer, but some how i cannot convert my .ui file to .py file, the only command that I found is

```
pyside6-uic myform.ui -o ui_myform.py
```

and

```
pyside-uic myform.ui > ui_myform.py
```

non of those two command works am getting the same error on my termnal
[image: pyside6 error message]

now i have try to Google this problem and the only answer i get is [How compile uic with PySide6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66672292/how-compile-uic-with-pyside6)

non of the option on the link above works.
just keep in mind am using python 3.11, qt 6.6 and pyside6 as shown below
[image: My Project enviroment]

Answer (score 0):

I fanally manage to make it work, still i dont know what the problem was, but the way i fixed it is by using venv and manualy install pyside6-uic-extendend and pyside6-utils.
Also i use the command line instead of power shell and it works. here is the command I use.

```
pyside-uic myform.ui > ui_myform.py
```

but the power shell is still not working, but atleast for now i can move on with learning.